# PayPal notify_url (IPN) never gets called, while return does get called

Tags: php, paypal

So, I'm trying to implement PayPal on my website but am struggling with the IPN functionality. I'm currently running everything on the sandbox.
The problem is that the URL I'm passing to PayPal through the "notify_url" param never gets called. I even tried setting up the URL directly in my sellers account settings (yes, also on the sandbox sellers account) but it still never gets called. I'm passing the URL here:

```
$paypal->add_field('return', $script_location.'?action=success');
$paypal->add_field('cancel_return', $script_location.'?action=cancel');
$paypal->add_field('notify_url', $script_location.'?action=ipn');
```

While the user gets redirected to ?action=success after a successful payment perfectly fine, ?action=ipn (the notify_url field) never gets called, no matter what.

Am I missing a setting or something?

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to send IPNs to?  Have you checked IPN History to make sure they aren't being sent but failing?

Comment: Is that URL accessible from the outside world?  (e.g., it's not "http://localhost" or "http://192.168.1.101" or some other address that wouldn't be accessible by PayPal?)  PayPal is the one making the post out to your IPN handler, so PayPal has to be able to access it.